# Is it enough to catch a PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

I hope this question isn't silly. In case it is I would be glad about an explanation.

I would like to treat constraint violations correctly.

Is it enough to surround my SQL Statement with **try & catch** to catch an PDOException in case there is a constraint violation like a **double primary key entry**, or do I need to check for that primary key column before the INSERT Statement?

Comment: I am not sure but I think I once saw code with try-catch arround an insert. When I replaced it with a check before the insert the performance decreased. You could compare both cases.

Comment: Thats what Im worried about aswell, I dont think there will be a difference since a I have hardly any data at the moment. I just wanted to know if people do it that way or if Im doing something wrong

Comment: There are a lot of different causes of a PDOException - some of which are recoverable, some of which are ignorable, others that might be critical to know about - so it's gonna depend a bit on what you do in that catch block.

Comment: Question Is why would you insert entry with pk that already exists? Anyway catching any pdo exception Is not enough. You should check that the caught exception represents unique constraint violation And not a connection timeout for example...

Comment: You might also consider using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in your query to handle the specific issue of duplicate primary keys.

Comment: I'd say: A user error should not raise an exception. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: @slepic if the user wants to create an object with **title = a** and that title already exists.

Comment: @ceejayoz thats exactly what I was looking for! if there is a duplicate key, I would need to abort the query I've found INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE will that do nothing?

Comment: @php_n00b If you want it to do nothing, use `INSERT IGNORE`. If you want it to do something, use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: Unless you lock the table for writing or manage to run everything within a single statement, checking the PK first does not guarantee it won't exist upon insertion. But determining the exact source of a PDOException (or even a key violation) is not trivial. Let's say they're simply two different tools.

Comment: that's a good question which is unjustly closed. But it is incomplete as well. Everything depends on your goal, what are you going to do in case of a duplicate key.